# Proteus - Copied subcircuit does not work even after renaming

Tags: proteus

I have a problem with subcircuits in Proteus software.

I know I should change the name of the subcircuit to work and it gives error when we don't.

But even when I change name and run simulation it still doesn't work and just the last subcircuit that I copied works.

The simulation is working and it gives no error in run or after runnig.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the technical details but my workaround for this problem is to change the "circuit name" for all the sub circuits to something else, and then changing them back to the real circuit name. this usually solves the problem for me.
I hope someone else posts a better answer.

Comment: Welcome back, I am sorry you waited so long for an answer. I wish I could solve it for but  I am not a user of Proteus.