# I have created a sub-circuit in Proteus but I can reuse it? How do I reuse it?

Tags: proteus, cad, subcircuit

Basically I want to pack a large number of components to form a small device. I will use this device many times. So I created a subcircuit and designed my circuit in it. But whenever I make a copy of it. It doesn't work. I read some stuff but it doesn't seems to solve the problem. How do I reuse my subcircuit?

Comment: See if this helps:
[Proteus - Copied subcircuit does not work even after renaming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/528370)

Comment: Thanks! I had to design a component to solve it. . Subcircuits have this issue. So if you want to reuse the circuits multiple times, you should go for components. Subcircuits should only be used to enclose a large circuit and make the overall look better